# SQL query to consolidate duplicates data with nulls

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a customer table with duplicated records, and the latest does not necessarily have the complete information e.g.:

| customer | Created at | last name | City | County | Adress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1-2-2022 | Adams | Null | United States | 34th str |
| A | 18-7-2023 | M. ADAMS | NY | United States | null |

My goal is to get rid of the duplication by getting the latest record info, if its null then bring the last record.

I want to get something like this

| customer | Created at | last name | City | County | Adress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 18-7-2023 | M. ADAMS | NY | United States | 34th str |

Anyone can help in this SQL code to achieve my end goal.

Note that the customer id is unique because the business people keep adding new customer instead of editing the old record existed.

When I tried to use `ifnull()` and `MAX()` but the result is not like what I'm expecting

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Google BigQuery? (Different syntax perhaps?)

Comment: Google BigQuery

Comment: How do you know that this is the same Adams? Does every last name only occur once in your database? Or do you assume that there only exists one person named Adams in the United States? Or is customer = 'A' supposed to be the unique customer ID? But if so, why can it occur twice in the table? Please clarify.

Comment: Because its associated with a company name, so you can call it a contact list. Same name with same company = same person. However, instead of updating the contact info the business is creating another contact which causes a unique id.

Comment: However, when they create another record they don't fill all of the info. So, soke of them are in the new record and the rest are in the history

Comment: It's b2b that's why it is associated to a company

Comment: Okay. So the table has a company ID that you are not showing or you even have separate tables per company. Yes? And in a company the name Adams (or Smith for that matter) can only occur once. Yes? So, if we see two rows, one with 'A. Adams' and one with 'B. Adams', these are considered to be the same person, because they have the same last name. Correct? And while you say that a later record can lack some info, it seems that every record can. Your first row lacks the city and the second the street. How does the customer column come into play? Is it of any importance here?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use window functions (e.g. first_value) for this:

```
with cte as (
    select customer
         , created_at
         , row_number() over (partition by customer order by created_at desc) as rn
         , first_value(last_name ignore nulls) over w as last_name
         , first_value(city ignore nulls) over w as city
         , first_value(county ignore nulls) over w as county
         , first_value(adress ignore nulls) over w as adress
    from t
    window w as (
        partition by customer
        order by created_at desc
        rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
    )
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first_value` window function to ignore nulls and fill the latest record with the all non-null(previous value if current value is null) and at the end remove all previous records as follows:

```
select customer, created_at, last_name, 
       ..... 
  FROM
  (select customer, created_at, 
          row_number() over w as rn,
          min(last_name ignore nulls) over w as last_name,
          ...
     from your_table t
     WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY created_at DESC)
) where rn = 1
```

Comment: I couldn't get the desired output with this query.. when it comes to the "Address" column... it retrieve null while I expect a value

Comment: Is your `address` actually a NULL value or null written as a string?

Comment: It's a null .. not  value

Comment: @Randy, '_null value_' is perfectly fine. (Used 480 times in the ANSI/ISO SQL standard specification.)

Comment: I'm trying to pull out the full info of the customer

Comment: If the business entered the address the first time and it happened that they created a new record for the same person and lifted the adress empty... I want to read the first address they entered. I hope I explained what I want to achieve clearly..  please look at the tables for better explication

Comment: MIN is supposed to ignore nulls, I doubt if this query works.